# How to make a background activity thatstops when the app stops

Tags: android

I'm making an android audio streaming app and i'm looking for a way to have some kind of a "ghost" activity handling streaming. This activity's public methods should be accessible from anywhere in the app but the streaming should stop as the app stops.

This would allow me to implement methods like "startStreaming(url)" "play()" "pause()" "next()" and have access to the progress of the song from anywhere in the app. Is that possible without using services ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use services?

Comment: Doesn't services continues to execute when the app closes ? Also it seems pretty hard to implement, i wanted a very simple solution like an activity empty of any xml running in foreground of the app

Comment: there is no such thing as a "background activity". Activities are either in the foreground, or not running at all

Comment: _"Doesn't services continues to execute when the app closes ?"_ You can programmatically stop a service for example based on activity life cycle methods.

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried with Activity Lifecycle?
With onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Know the statuses of your app to make what ever you want if the user change the status.

[Statuses Of your App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ9Xe.png)

Comment: Well i'll check that then come back to you

Comment: Aren't these methods corresponding to a particular activity of the app ? I mean, is there a method that i can override in the service wich will be called when the user is no longer in the app ?

Comment: Yes, you need to override those methods to do what ever you want to do if when the user change his status, for example onStop() is when the user is no longer watching the activity or the app, and onDestroy() is when the user destroys the App and will no longer be oppen in background. @PhilémonRoubaud